# Condition based page size and filters of Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way to control the filters and page size options of my Kendo Grid?

Ex: I've a Kendo grid with some filters and page size. Now I want to remove some of the filters for selected columns. Also page size based on login (or some condition).

Is there any way to handle this? from controller or from my view?

Comment: If it is based on login why do not create the grid with the right filter and pagesize options? You can initialize this grid options based on your conditions and the (and only then) initialize the Grid widget.

Comment: Hi OnaBai thanks for the reply. Actually my requirement is, grid is same for all logins. But for few users I want to disable filters.

Comment: But as far as I understand first you login then you create the Grid, right? Why do not create the grid depending on the user profile?

Comment: No, I've already a grid in my .cshtml view with datasource.  i.e  dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "/Employee/GetAll",
                    dataType: "json"
                }, like this. And one more thing can we use sessions here? is it suggestible to use sessions in MVC4?

Comment: Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/U9LQ4/1/. Of course it is not .cshtml but my code is already generated and then at execution time is when it decides what to do depending on the user that choose. If you type _OnaBai_ you have `filtering` and a  `pageSize` of 20, otherwise there is no `filtering` and `pageSize` is 5.

Comment: Thank you, this is what exactly I'm looking for. But when I try to implement, it is giving error like cannot resolve symbol filterable.    var filterable = false;
        var pagesize = 5;


        @if(Session["login"].ToString() == "abc")
        {
            filterable = true;
        }

Comment: Hi OnaBai thanks for your help. I got it now. When I give @HttpContext.Current.Session["login"].ToString() it is working fine :)

Comment: I've added an answer with what we discussed in the comments so other people will find the answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the filters dynamically, and since in your case you only need to change it depending on the login, the idea would be creating the grid with the right values. I.e., emit the code from the server but use as value for `filterable` and `pageSize` a JavaScript variable that gets its value in execution time and depending on the user logged in.

Example: I define a login form that when user clicks on a Login `button` it executes the Grid initialization that since then it is empty.

Form:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="form" class="k-block">
        <div class="k-header">Login Form</div>
        <div>Login : <input id="user" type="text" data-role="autocomplete"/></div>
        <button class="k-button" id="doLogin">Login</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript intercepting click on `doLogin` button:

```
$("#doLogin").click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Code for reading user logged-in and setting the default value for `pageSize` and `filterable` or user specific value:

```
var user = $("#user").val();
// Default value
var filterable = false;
var pagesize = 5;
// Specific value
if (user == "OnaBai") {
    pagesize = 20;
    filterable = true;
}
```

Now, proceed with the initialization of the `DataSource` and the `Grid`. We will use `filterable` and `pageSize` JavaScript variables for the initialization.

```
// pageSize is variable, the remaining code is the same no matter of the user
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize: pagesize,
    transport: {
        ...
    },
    ...
};

// Create a DIV element and a Grid on it.
var grid = $("<div id='grid'></div>").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    filterable: filterable,
    ...
});
// Append Grid element to the correct place of the HTML page
grid.appendTo($("#container"));
```

See a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/U9LQ4/1/